# problems in comparing two dates in php, minutes always 0

Tags: php, datetime, datediff

I'm gonna need to set up same date comparisons and I'm practicing first with this php code, however no matter how I alter the date I end up getting the hours and seconds but the minutes is always 0. Btw, ideally I would like to be able to write the date in the european format `dd/mm/yy hh:mm` however this didn't work so I adjusted it to the US format. Anyway thanks for the help.

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
$date= new DateTime('2015-06-21 18:32:00');
$now = new DateTime();
$interval = $date->diff($now);
echo "difference " . $interval->d . " days, " . $interval->h." hours, ".$interval->m." minutes";
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to calculate the difference between two dates using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php)

Comment: No, I already checked all of those to come up with this code, it doesn't solve the problem tho, the answer below did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a simple mistake with the property used to represent the intervals minutes, its `i` and not `m`. `m` is in fact the Months property.

This is also how you would set the date using the European format

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s', '21/06/2015 18:32:00');
$now = new DateTime();
$interval = $date->diff($now);
echo "difference " . $interval->d . " days, " . $interval->h." hours, ".$interval->i." minutes";
```

If you do a `print_r($interval)` you will get to see all the properties like this

```
DateInterval Object
(
    [y] => 0
    [m] => 0
    [d] => 0
    [h] => 6
    [i] => 4
    [s] => 15
    [weekday] => 0
    [weekday_behavior] => 0
    [first_last_day_of] => 0
    [invert] => 1
    [days] => 0
    [special_type] => 0
    [special_amount] => 0
    [have_weekday_relative] => 0
    [have_special_relative] => 0
)
```

Comment: Can this be incorporated into a SQL query, I want to load all items where the date field is less than the current date.. would it be something like `SELECT * FROM table WHERE datefield < NOW()`?

Comment: Yes but thats really another question. You can also use `WHERE datefield BETWEEN '2015-01-01 00:00:01' AND '2015-02-01 00:00:01'` type syntax

Comment: I know but I don't want to wait 90 minutes to ask another question, so I'd really appreciate if you could be able to help me here. I don't really understand how that would work tho, I don't need it to be in any interval as long as it's less than the current time

Comment: The syntax is exactly as you used in your first comment

Answer (score 2):

Use $interval->i for minutes, $interval->m is for months.